# How to open a .dict file for use in android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dictionary

I have been working on an `android` app that relies on reading in a large number of word list from a storage file of some sort. I have been using word list stored on `sqlite` database. Recently found a .`dict` file in an app that I thought has better list of words. But I couldn't really find a tool to either explore it or a piece of code to help me show how the words are organized inside the `.dict` file. Has anyone come across such a scenario before?. If so, It would be great if you help out. Thanks.

Comment: It may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICT, which means its human readable.  But it could also be a custom file format.  You kind of just need to open it in a text editor (to see if its human readable) or hex editor and figure it out

Comment: Have tried using notepad, and notepad++. nothing

Comment: Then you can try a hex editor and see if you can decode anything, but odds are good its a proprietary format